# HttpClientFactory: Typed HttpClient with additional constructor arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

With [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) we can configure dependancy injection to create and manage the lifetime of HttpClients:

```
public class GitHubService : IGitHubService
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public GitHubService(HttpClient client)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
        // GitHub API versioning
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept",
            "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
        // GitHub requires a user-agent
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

        Client = client;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<GitHubIssue>> GetAspNetDocsIssues()
    {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(
            "/repos/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues?state=open&sort=created&direction=desc");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
            <IEnumerable<GitHubIssue>>(responseStream);
    }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs we configure DI:

```
services.AddHttpClient<GitHubService>();
```

However, if the typed client has additional constructor arguments, how should these be provided?
For example, if a repository name was to be passed in:

```
public class GitHubService : IGitHubService
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }
    private readonly string _repositoryName;

    public GitHubService(HttpClient client, string repositoryName)
    {
        _repositoryName = repositoryName;

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
        // GitHub API versioning
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept",
            "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
        // GitHub requires a user-agent
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

        Client = client;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<GitHubIssue>> GetAspNetDocsIssues()
    {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(
            $"/repos/aspnet/{_repositoryName}/issues?state=open&sort=created&direction=desc");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
            <IEnumerable<GitHubIssue>>(responseStream);
    }
}
```

Perhaps this isn't a realistic example, but how would dependency injection be configured to provide the repository name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to get this working by switching to named clients:

```
//To start with, create a named client:
services.AddHttpClient("GitHubClient", ctx => { ctx.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/"); });

//Then set up DI for the TypedClient
services.AddTransient<IGitHubService>(ctx =>
{
    var clientFactory = ctx.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("GitHubClient");
 
    return new GitHubService(httpClient, repositoryName);
});
```

Comment: Should this be transient or singleton?

Comment: Recommended use for httpclient.


To summarize recommended HttpClient use in terms of lifetime management, you should use either long-lived clients and set PooledConnectionLifetime (.NET Core and .NET 5+) or short-lived clients created by IHttpClientFactory.

In .NET Core and .NET 5+:

Use a static or singleton HttpClient instance with PooledConnectionLifetime set to the desired interval, such as 2 minutes, depending on expected DNS changes.

Answer (score 14):

An alternative if you don't want to use the named clients is to create a custom class for the extra parameters.
Because the problem is that it does not know what to resolve for the type string, what you can do is to create an object with a string property that will contain the value that you want to pass, register it as a singleton and let the container resolve it.

Create a class that contains all the extra parameters. In your case "repositoryName"

```
public class RepositoryConfig
{
    public string RepositoryName {get; set;}
}
```

Register the new class

```
services.AddSingleton(new RepositoryConfig { RepositoryName = "MyRepo"});
```

Then register the HttpClient

```
services.AddHttpClient<IGitHubService, GitHubService>();
```

Now your class will be instantiated correctly.

Answer (score 9):

There is actually a simple enough way to do this in one step.

```
services.AddHttpClient<IGitHubService, GitHubService>((client, sp) =>
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
   return new GitHubService(client, repositoryName);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can pass a parameter through the `HttpClient`s properties. Repository name can be passed through `BaseAddress`.

```
var repositoryName = // load from a config for example

services.AddHttpClient<GitHubService>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api.github.com/repos/aspnet/{repositoryName}");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately for my real use case, the parameter was in the query string and I could not update the the service I was calling.  I ended up using named clients. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) as a dependency resolver you can achieve this with it's [Delegate Factories](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html).

It will look something like this

```cs
public delegate GitHubService GitHubServiceFactory(string repositoryName);
```

```cs
public class AnotherService
{
    private GitHubService gitHubService;
    public AnotherService(GitHubServiceFactory gitHubServiceFactory)
    {
        this.gitHubService = gitHubServiceFactory("myRepositoryName");
    }
}
```

As far as I know this is not possible with the builtin dependency resolver.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use the `AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>(Func<HttpClient, IServiceProvider, TImplementation>)` [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0##Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions_AddHttpClient__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_Net_Http_HttpClient_System_IServiceProvider___1__):

```
services.AddHttpClient<IGitHubService, GitHubService>((client, sp) =>
    // any other constructor dependencies in GitHubService will be filled in
    // by ActivatorUtilities from the provided IServiceProvider
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<GitHubService>(sp, client, repositoryName)
);
```